# Why the Axi lite bus occpuies two BRAM_18K?

Tags: fpga, synthesis, vivado-hls

Below is my simple code:

```
void MyFunc(float input[10], float output[10])
{
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=input bundle=BUS_INPUT

const float temp[10]={
0.0f,0.1f,0.2f,0.3f,0.4f,0.5f,0.6f,0.7f,0.8f,0.9f
};


for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
output[i]=input[i]+temp[i];
}
}
```

After synthesis, the resource utilization is shown below,

Synthesis result :

[image]

From this figure, I am surprised to find that two BRAM_18K blocks are used. Is this normal? and why the Axi lite bus can occpuy two BRAM_18K?

I have checked the generated verilog code and still could not find the reason. The generated verilog code is put in 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iP6JQGbv6pShGuCF62G21isRHkjJhn3I/view?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Comment: The bus itself doesn't consume any block ram, it's some of your modules in the design that actually consume the ram blocks. Like the `int_input_r` instance of `MyFunc_BUS_INPUT_s_axi_ram`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware will process one block of a data, producing second block of data. Both blocks must be stored somewhere, and that storage is block ram units, as inferred by compiler.